How to Setup RestClientCall in Xunit
I had the code below to set up the rest client. But after upgrading to.NET 8 and upgrading RestSharpt to the latest version, RestResponse is giving an error saying 'There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter request for RestResponse'.
My Code.
 var response = new RestResponse<T>()
 {
     StatusCode = statusCode,
     Data = dataResult,
     RawBytes = rawBytesResult
 };
 mockClient.Setup(x => x.CallHttpClient<T>(It.IsAny<RestRequest>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(response));


Below code fixed the error
   var response = new RestResponse<T>(new RestRequest("apitest/test", Method.Get))
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode,
        Data = dataResult,
        RawBytes = rawBytesResult
    };
    mockClient.Setup(x => x.CallHttpClient<T>(It.IsAny<RestRequest>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(response));

